# How to format list of objects in Terraform variable definition?

Tags: terraform

I'm using Terraform 1.0.4 and having an issue with a complex object definition that includes this piece:

```
    groups = list(object({
      group = string

    }))
```

I've tried various syntax, for example:

```
          groups = {{group = "D", group = "K"}}
```

to get this defined in the .tfvars file I'm using, but I can't get this to work.

Thanks much for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `groups` is a **list**. So it should be:

```
groups = [{group = "D"}, {group = "K"}]
```